# need help with a condition while looping through an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I have an array with about 20 elements, and I need to do a few if statements while looping through this array and I need help in creating this if statement in the sense that i need to be able to search if the string contains some text in an efficient way that won't hang up the whole app.

```
var locations = [
                   ['Maryland', 'USA', 'Pentium IV', 120, '1 GB', '15"'],
                   ['New York', 'USA', 'Pentium IV', 40, '512 MB', '15" and 17"'],
              ['Frankfurt', 'Germany', 'Pentium IV', 100, '2 GB', '17"']
                ];

for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
     var ram = locations[4];
     var monitor = locations[5];

     // need help with the if statement below
     if (ram < '1 GB' || monitor.startsWith("15")) {
       // do something
     }
}
```

i am using pure javascript, no jquery or other frameworks.

thank you very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
if (ram.indexOf('GB') >= 0)
```

This will just check if the word 'GB' is contained in the string. If it is, we're sure it's 1GB, 2GB, etc. If it's not, we're probably talking in MB, since Terabytes of RAM is not used in machines yet.

Offcourse this depends on what the possible choices of RAM are. Do they come from a (finite) list, or can the users type them themselves?

Answer (score 2):

You have double arrays here, so you need to `locations[i]` to refer to the right row. By the way, there's no `startsWith` function in Javascript.

Try this:-

```
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
     var ram = locations[i][4];
     var monitor = locations[i][5];

     if ((ram.indexOf('MB') >= 0 && parseInt(ram) < 1024) || monitor.match("^15")) {
       // do something
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is single threaded, so in lieu of using [web workers](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-workers/current-work/) which is a rather new thing that allows you to run it in the background, you should just do what you want in the loop.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: I read the question wrong, I thought he asked if he could dispatch the job inside of the for loop somewhere else. My bad.